# How to loop collection and apply multiple tasks

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to achieve the following in Ansible YAML. I have a collection of environment objects. I'd like to loop through them and complete 3 tasks on each object. I've seen a loop keyword but not with multiple tasks. What is the neatest way to achieve this in Ansible YAML?

**The collection**

```
- artifactPath: 'C:/artifacts/artifact'

- envs:
  - [{
       name: 'ENV1',
       path: 'C:/site/env1',
       config: 'env1.config'
     },
     {
       name: 'ENV2',
       path: 'C:/site/env2',
       config: 'env2.config'
     }]
```

**The Tasks**

```
- name {{name}} Task1 Clean down target directory {{path}}
  win_file
    path: "{{path}}"
    state: absent
```

```
- name {{name}} Task2 Copy files
  win_copy:
    remote_src:yes
    src: "{{artifactPath}}"
    dest: "{{path}}"
```

```
- name {{name}} Task3 Override config
  win_copy:
    remote_src:yes
    src: "{{artifactPath}}/{{config}}"
    dest: "{{path}}/config.json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The play below shows how you can iterate the list

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    artifactPath: 'C:/artifacts/artifact'
    envs:
      - name: ENV1
        path: 'C:/site/env1'
        config: 'env1.config'
      - name: ENV2
        path: 'C:/site/env2'
        config: 'env2.config'

  tasks:

    - name: Task1 Clean target directory
      debug:
        msg: |
          win_file:
            path: "{{ item.path }}"
            state: absent
      loop: "{{ envs }}"

    - name: Task2 Copy files
      debug:
        msg: |
          win_copy:
            remote_src: yes
            src: "{{ artifactPath }}"
            dest: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ envs }}"

    - name: Task3 override config
      debug:
        msg: |
          win_copy:
            remote_src: yes
            src: "{{ artifactPath }}/{{ item.config }}"
            dest: "{{ item.path }}/config.json"
      loop: "{{ envs }}"
```

- The consistency of the win_* parameters is up to you.
- You can declare the label in each loop to make the output easier to read

```yaml
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this logic separated out to a file loaded by include_tasks from the playbook? I'm guessing it'd be stripped back to simply have the envs declaration/initialisation and the tasks with the loop syntax.